# How can I show the uploaded image in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm going to upload an image with react now. When I selected the image and received the value of the selected image in state, I got an array like below. But how do I approach this array to see this selected image? If you look at the picture, there is no path to the picture in the array, so I want to know which value to choose to see the picture. I'd appreciate it if you let me know, thanks.

[image]

```
import React from 'react'
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

function MakeModal() {

  const fileInput = React.useRef(null);
  
  const [isfile,setIsfile] = useState("");
  
  const handleButtonClick = e => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

  const handleChange = e => {
    setIsfile(e.target.files[0]);
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
  }; 

  const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(isfile);

  console.log('check',objectUrl)

  return (
    <Modal>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>
              <input 
                type="file" 
                style={{display:'none'}}
                ref={fileInput}
                onChange={handleChange}
                multiple={true}/>
              <button 
                className='box9_2_3_3_2'
                onClick={handleButtonClick}>
                choose img
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </Modal>
  )
}



export default MakeModal;

const Modal = styled.div`
  display: ${props=>props.isModal===true?'block':'none'};
  position: fixed;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.65);
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 500343;

  .box9_2_3_3_2 {
    background-color: rgb(0,149,246)!important;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    color: white;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
  }
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to create an ObjectUrl from your file like this :

```
const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);  // or file[0] if it's an array

...
  <img src={objectUrl} ... />
...
```

A good practise is to **revoke** the URL when the compenent unmount, or when the file change. One exemple is to do it like this, it depends on your logic :

```
const [isFile, setIsFile] = useState('');
const [preview, setPreview] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  if (isFile) {
    const objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(isFile); // create here
    setPreview(objectUrl);
  }
  return () => URL.revokeObjectURL(isFile);      // And revoke on unmount
}, [isFile]); // or whatever you called the variable you put the file in

return (
  ...
    <img src={preview} ... />
  ...
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But  'Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed'. error occured. I uploaded the code, but can I know where it went wrong?

Comment: @MontaKr, look at my second exemple, with useEffect you only create the object when file (or isFile in your case) is defined. As isFile is undefined before select a image you have this error :)